# Is there a way to tell the difference between a thunderbolt cable and a MiniDP cable (possible knockoff)?

Tags: mini-displayport, thunderbolt

I purchased a thunderbolt cable off eBay and connected it to my Apple monitor.  So far, the video signal is working fine; however, the audio is not coming out of the monitor as I understand that it should.

How can I tell if my cable is actually a thunderbolt cable and not a mini display port cable (meaning only video is supported, none of the other thunderbolt features)? It does have the lightening bolt on the cable ends, but could it be a knockoff?

Comment: In your system preferences, does thunderbolt show up as an option for your audio destination?

Comment: "How can I tell if my cable is actually a thunderbolt cable" - Replace a known good TB cable with it and see if the devices still work as expected.  As-is, we can't ID it for you, as we cant' see or test it, nor is that really on-topic for SU.  Perhaps edit your question on rephrase it to be about finding out why your audio doesn't work (include system specs, etc.)?